# Leaflet Control Search Error: Uncaught TypeError: L.Control.geocoder is not a function

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am new to Leaflet and I'm trying to add the Control Search in my map but I encounter this error

> Uncaught TypeError: L.Control.geocoder is not a function

I already added these links

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-control-geocoder/dist/Control.Geocoder.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-control-geocoder/dist/Control.Geocoder.js"></script>
```

I initialized my map

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([40.71455, -74.00712], 10);
```

Then added basemap

```
var dark_matrix = L.tileLayer('https://tiles.stadiamaps.com/tiles/alidade_smooth_dark/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png', {
minZoom: 3,
maxZoom: 20,
attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://stadiamaps.com/">Stadia Maps</a>, &copy; <a href="https://openmaptiles.org/">OpenMapTiles</a> &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
});
dark_matrix.addTo(map);
```

Add the control like this

```
L.Control.geocoder().addTo(map);
```

I also tried this one

```
var searchControl = L.Control.geocoder();
searchControl.addTo(map);
```

But still does not work.

Here is the jsfiddle of the project https://jsfiddle.net/mgy01hwx/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the order of the script files. The plugin needs leaflet code to be imported first in order to work.

- first import leaflet.js
- then import leaflet-geocoder.js

  ```
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA==" crossorigin=""></script> 
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-control-geocoder/dist/Control.Geocoder.js"></script>
  ```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mvjfegyu/)

Comment: Ohh I don't know level of hierarchy is important, thank you!

Comment: Interestingly enough I have the correct order but still get this error. I even restarted my local server (VS Live Server extension) since sometimes a simple refresh doesn't cut it.